# CPU does not support KVM but I want to run andriod emulator in Ubuntu 18.04 on HP Computer

Tags: android, react-native, kvm

I have set up my react Native environment on an HP UEFI Computer running Ubuntu 18.04. When I try to run an emulator using AVD, I get the following error

**

> Starting emulator for AVD 'AVD_for_Nexus_10_by_Google' emulator:
>   ERROR: x86_64 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
>   Please ensure KVM is properly installed and usable. CPU acceleration
>   status: KVM requires a CPU that supports vmx or svm

**

I have tried to install kVM as shown online and when I run

**

> ~$ sudo /usr/sbin/kvm-ok

**

I get the error

> INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions KVM acceleration can
>   NOT be used

Any help or directions on this issue especially how to get my Emulator running will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This really is more of a question for AskUbuntu.com, for help in getting KVM installed and working (if that is possible in your case).

Comment: Please go to bios and turn on hardware acceleration.

Comment: I dont see anyhing like Acceleration on my bios

Comment: it will be by the name virtualization

Comment: link for turning it on https://askubuntu.com/questions/256792/how-do-i-enable-hardware-virtualization-technology-vt-x-for-use-in-virtualbox

Comment: There is no virtualization either. infact the Bios seem to lack lots of things

Answer (score 0):

first you check whether KVM is currently installed on Linux. If not installed, you can install as follow the below steps.

1. install the cpu-checker package

   `$ sudo apt-get install cpu-checker`
2. After Installation ,

   `$ egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo`

this command result is 4 or 12 or..etc

3. Run the the `kvm-ok` command.
   see this picture [image]

If the problem isn't resolved after that, I guess, can't access to `/dev/kvm` directory of android studio. you can change the permission. run this command.

```
`sudo chmod 777 -R /dev/kvm`
```

You will be asked for your password. Enter it correctly and restart the android studio. see this picture. [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can consider rebooting your computer,

1. **Access the BIOS Setup** from your list of options, select "**BIOS Setup**". this is usually done by highlighting "BIOS Setup" and pressing the Enter Key specified on your system (often F1O or similar).
2. **Navigate to Advanced Settings**: Inside the BIOS Setup, you will need to navigate to the '*Advanced*' or 'System Configuration' section. Use the arrow keys to move through the available options.
3. **Enable VT-x**: Look for an option related to "**Virtualization Technology**" or "**VT-x**". Select this option and change it from "Disable" to ""Enable".
4. Save and Exit: After enabling the VT-x, find the "Save Changes and Exit" or similar.
   Then Restart your Computer.
   Once you have completed these steps, VT-x should be enabled on your PC and you can use virtualization features as needed.

To verify this you may consider opening your terminal and run the command

```
egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
```

Here the output should be a number greater than 0 with that you are ready to install what you need.

Comment: did you use any AI at all in the writing of any part of this answer?